# Threejs draw a path with textures

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to draw a path in my 3D world, but the class of line is not useful. Who can help me?!
Like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbZje.jpg)

**Now I fixed my question**

1. I want draw a path ，and fill it with texture

   ```
   var SUBDIVISIONS = 20;
   geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
   var curve = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3();
   curve.v0 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 110);
   curve.v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 200, 110);
   curve.v2 = new THREE.Vector3(200, 200, 110);
   for (j = 0; j < SUBDIVISIONS; j++) {
       geometry.vertices.push( curve.getPoint(j / SUBDIVISIONS) )
   }

   material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, linewidth: 5 } );
   line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
   scene.add(line);
   ```

*this way has two problem 1：linewidth is not support on Windows ，2: LineBasicMaterial not support texture*

2. So i search on google find class  Three.MeshLine. linewidth is Ok,but texture mapping not fine. texture code there:`var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
   loader.load( 'assets/images.png', function( texture ) {
       strokeTexture = texture;
       strokeTexture.wrapS = strokeTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
       strokeTexture.repeat.set( 5, 1);
       strokeTexture.needsUpdate = true;
       init()
   } );`
   Regardless of the setting the texture and MeshLineMaterial ，The result is not what I want result image：[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGNwV.png)

Comment: And where is the code you tried?

Comment: I see this is one of your first Question on Stack Overflow, welcome! Please provide some code so we can see what you have tried and better understand the context of your question, which in turn will help us out to help you. Also see [How To ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask better question which lead to better answers.

Comment: @Dekel thank you.  It's on my work pc  ,I knew threejs. Line may be not supported textures map.   I wan get a way to do it

Comment: @RaymonddelaCroix thanks  the is my first post  on this web site . and my English is poor.  But I need help

Comment: It looks like you need someone to write the code for you.

Comment: @Dekel  i need a  method。

Comment: @Dekel you know in China the network is closed, about threejs Resources seldom。i only one way to ask a way to do

Comment: Did you read the comment by Raymond ?

Comment: @Dekel yes。I will fix it on tomorrow。 now use iPhone cannot code

Comment: @Dekel my question is give me an idea use threejs draw path like top link

Comment: @Dekel You could also downvote and vote to close...

Comment: @Wilt he said he will fix it

Comment: I suggest you close your question, carefully read the links in  @RaymonddelaCroix his comment and try again.

Comment: @Dekel Tomorrow? Next week? You can upvote again after he fixed his question.

Comment: @Wilt Not so sure why you care so much, but I vote to close :)

Comment: @Dekel I care because the average quality of the three.js questions is terrible and a bit of googling will get OP similar answer as posted below.

Comment: @Wilt thanks. Later I will code there.  Very thank

Comment: @Wilt got it! Fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine - it's an implementation of mesh-based lines. Also note the references on that site, could give you some insights.

Otherwise you might want to look into creating a shape from the line. This could be done using the `THREE.ShapeGeometry`-class.

Comment: Thank very much ,the meshline I was try and shape geometry. I can draw this path. But do not know how to mapping